# Winform, mouse click out of popup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a small popup window , and I'd like to trigger event when I click the mouse outside of the window bound.

I've tried initiating it on OnMouseClick, and check if the mouse cursor is out of the pop up bounds, but it doesn't seem to trigger out of the popup bounds.

Comment: Show some sample codes of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Batuta, I don't mind pasting , but the event won't trigger so the code inside the event is irrelevant, I feel that this is more an events question rather than pure how-to-code question.

Comment: The event won't trigger unless the form is actually clicked.  So clicking outside of the window is more difficult to register.  You're going to need to register a global hook.  There are examples already.  An alternative would be to use the form's LostFocus event and just assume that if the form loses focus, they clicked outside of it.  That won't be without limitations though.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There might be a simpler solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For discussion:

```
public partial class FrmPopup : Form {

    public FrmPopup() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    const uint WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCACTIVATE && m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) {
            if(!ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)) && MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                label1.Text = "Clicked outside of window";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Deactivate event?  This will fire when the form loses focus.  This could be from a mouse click OR a context switch, but may deliver what you want.